# iPhone Retina Display with Apple App Store Upload

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have read the Apple's "News and Announcement" as below:

> **Using Identifiers in Your Apps** March 21, 2013 Starting May 1, the App
>   Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs.
>   Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor
>   or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6. You can find more
>   details in the UIDevice Class Reference.
>
> **Make Your Apps Look Great on the Retina Display and iPhone 5** March 21,
>   2013 Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone
>   apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. Learn about
>   preparing your apps by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

For the UDID, I don't worry about that. But for the second constraint, how can I make sure my app is a Retina display support? Does it mean for every image or icon inside the app must be in Retina display resolution? If there is any one of the image is not in Retina display resolution, Apple will reject my app to be uploaded?

Comment: It just means that if you are using background images or buttons images etc etc.. Make sure you change those images a larger size that is specified for retina display. As far as rejection of your app, it is possible. So just change the sizes and upload or update the existing apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They haven't offered more details past that email, but I would say that they would want all of your images to be of retina quality, ideally. Now if there are a couple images that are not retina quality (but it's not obvious), then the reviewer will likely be lenient. However, if the app is ugly and pixelated, then your app will definitely be rejected. I would try to update all of your images to retina quality. Fewer and fewer people are using non-retina devices every day (the only devices sold without a retina display are the iPad 2 and iPad Mini), and the last iPhone without a retina display was the iPhone 3GS, unveiled nearly four years ago, and outdated three years ago.